# Show that the multiplication lies in FL

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

I don't know exactly how to solve the exercise below.

> Show that the multiplication lies in $\text{FL}$.
>
> Hint: A useful approach to a solution is to split the exercise into two parts and to explain that each function lies in $\text{FL}$. The standard multiplication scheme can be used as an intermediate step. Example:
>
> $\begin{align}
> 1001 \cdot{} 1100 & = \\
>  1001000\\
>  + \ \ \ 100100\\
>  + \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\\
>  + \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\\
> \end{align}$
>
> Other useful approaches are certainly also accepted.

Useful definitions from our lecture notes:

---

Let $f : \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ be a function, let $t : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be a time bound and let $s : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be a memory space bound.

$\bullet$ It is $f \in \text{FDTIME}(t),$ if there exists a DTM $M$ with an output tape, calculating $f$ and for which $T_M \in O(t)$ holds.

$\bullet$ It is $A \in \text{FDSPACE}(s),$ if there exists an offline DTM $M$, calculating $f$ and for which $S_M \in O(s)$ holds. The fields being written on the output band are not considered for the amount of memory space.

$\text{FP}=\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb N} \text{FDTIME}(n^k), \text{FL}=\text{FDSPACE}(\log n)$

---

I think the hint wants me to find two functions (one for the multiplication and one for the addition), but I don't see how to find two functions that do the calculation of the example in the appropriate way. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Can somebody else also write an answer, please? I still have difficulties with this exercise and it makes me very sad, because I've spent already several hours for it.

Comment: The same question was asked on math.stackexchange a while ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75770/proof-that-a-multiplication-verification-can-be-done-in-log-space

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Thanks for the link (or better: Toda), but the only answer there talks about the facts, not how to show them or even how to provide an appropriate solution for my exercise. I don't know, maybe the solution is 2 sides long and so nobody wants to write it down here in this thread.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: So considering the example above, the input tape would contain $1001 \cdot{} 1100$, the work tape would contain the four summands with all carry and the output tape would contain the result? So far, so good but is this already an acceptable solution?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I'm then wondering how the Turing machine can do the calculation. What is this information?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I certainly always try to make myself familiar with a certain topic, before I start a thread. So obviously I didn't find the answer to this exercise and that's why I'm using the forum and asking for help. It seems to me that you don't really want to help me and you are right to do so, but for the sake of fairness please simply don't post something in my threads, so helpful users can see that there is a need for help, without having to read ~30 comments. I'm an undergraduate and have huge difficulties with the compulsory lecture "Complexity Theory". What else can I say?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider the standard multiplication scheme. Suppose that we compute the sum column by column, starting with the LSB. How big is the carry we have to remember?

Comment: Multiplication is actually in NC<sup>1</sup> (hard) and even in TC<sup>0</sup> (harder).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The carry has always the size 1. But to be honest I fail to take the hint; maybe my way of thinking is too complicated... NC and TC haven't been introduced in the lecture so far (I've heard them for the first time).

Comment: In the example four rows of bits are added. But I really don't know, why the carry doesn't have size 1. I mean if for example 1+1 then I write 0 and remember 1; if 1+0 then I write 1 and there is no carry.

Comment: For example 1111+1111=11110 and this addition has 4 carry digits. So the total number of carry digits depends on the length of the binary (worst case). Is this what you mean?

Comment: Now I see that the carry can grow dramatically. But how do I determine the general case and how does this help me to solve the exercise?

Comment: I don't know if you get notified when there is a message in chat, but if you could have a look into it or give some further help in this thread, it would be much appreciated, since I still have difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia gives great information about the complexity of various [elementary operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations).

Multiplication takes $n^2$ time by the "school-book" algorithm, and thus it is in $\mathsf{FTIME}(n^2)$ and in $\mathsf{FL}$. Better solutions exist.

Also, it's quite simple to see that all you need is 3 registers of size $2\log n$, to complete the schoolbook algorithm, so the problem is $\mathsf{FSPACE}(\log n)$

Comment: Multiplication is complete for TC^0 and provably not in NC^0.

Comment: It is not even in AC0. The paper proved equivalences under AC0 reductions not that they are in AC0.

Comment: @kaveh, I must be missing something, but their Thm3.1 along with Prop2.1 (part 3) makes all the problem they show there in $AC^0$, not?

Comment: I think I see the problem, nevermind that.