# Largest parallelization speedup for multiplication of very large numbers

Tags: parallel-computing, multiplication

I have recently come across the following papers:

- S. Baktir and E. Savas. Highly-parallel Montgomery multiplication for multi-core general-purpose microprocessors.
  In E. Gelenbe and R. Lent, editors, Computer and Information Sciences III, pages 467–476.
  Springer London, 2013.
- P. Giorgi, L. Imbert, and T. Izard. Parallel modular multiplication on multi-core processors. In Computer
  Arithmetic (ARITH), 2013 21st IEEE Symposium on, pages 135–142, April 2013.
- B. S. Fagin, "Large integer multiplication on massively parallel processors," [1990 Proceedings] The Third Symposium on the Frontiers of Massively Parallel Computation, College Park, MD, 1990, pp. 38-42.

where they deal with the issue of computing a multiplication between large numbers (in the first two papers, up to approx $2^{14}$ bits, in the last one up to $2^{23}$ bits) using many processors simultaneously.

I was wondering: what happens beyond that? What is the theoretical maximum speedup for a $2^n$ bit multiplication, having an unlimited amount of processors at disposal? Can the wallclock time of the operation be made arbitrarily small? I guess there are communication bottlenecks among the processors?

Comment: Please specify your model of computation. Because at some point physical limits and circuit limits (e.g. ignoring spacetime we live in a 3 dimensional world) and the speed of light limits come into play, if you want to be realistic.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7024/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29,